# what are possible benefits of having separate layer/a dedicated schema for each layer in ETL (extract , transform and load)?

Tags: etl, analytics, data-warehouse, business-intelligence, azure-synapse

what are possible benefits of having separate layer/a dedicated schema for each layer in ETL (extract , transform and load), I mean one dedicated layer for staging , one for type 1 persistent tables and a dedicated schema/layer for tables at dimensional model ? why it is not recommended to have all tables in one schema?

Thanks,
Rajneesh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Restaurant Metaphor:**

> **Datawarehouse is like a restaurant**. You get vegetables, ingredients from multiple groceries. But, you cannot prepare the food in the table of
>   the customer.
>
> - You need separate area called *store room* to keep the vegetables.
> - You need separate area called *kitchen top* to check quality of vegetables, clean the vegetables, cut the vegetables to conform to
>     right size for the recipe, add right ingredients and make the final
>     recipe.
> - You need separate area called *banquet hall* to serve final recipe to customer.

Now, take the case of data warehouse.

- You need to get different data coming from different source systems. some of them from ORACLE, some from Teradata, some from Enterprise Message System etc.  The goal of staging area is for storing raw data. There are dependencies between ingredients. You need to have all of them to prepare the recipe. *You need to have them in the staging layer. It is same like store room.*
- The data is cleansed, validated, conformed to right dimensions, added with additional keys, data transformed to suit the data warehouse.  Mostly these transformations happen in memory. In some cases, there could be intermediate storage into tables. *It is transformation layer. It is same like Kitchen top.*
- The transformed data is loaded into datawarehouse tables. It is loaded into dimensional model. *It is the presentation layer or loading layer. It is the banquet hall, where food is available for buffet dinner.*

So, you need three separate layers, so that all of them can be working without interrutping others. There are also additional factors like:

- Security pertaining to different layers
- Troubleshooting of the data issue to the source
- Historical data maintenance
- Meeting compliance
- Completely rebuilding data warehouse, if needed from staging area
- many more

Comment: Thanks Venkat and Cedersved for providing good insights. If possible ,what kind of resources can be managed at schema level, I mean we can set limit or total % to each schema from total available at DB level? 
Also I guess maintenance will be different for each schema, example more frequent gather stats for final target layer in data warehouse than staging layer.
I was wondering if this will offer better database resource management because each layer is having different data processing needs and hence need different amount of resource.

Comment: These are all design specific. You can have them in separate databases or separate schema. The resource manager you want to put for the ETL is something you have to make a decision based on your loads.

Answer (score 1):

I would say this approach provides clearity. It'll be easier for developers to have an overall idea of dependencies and where to look when for example troubleshooting if you have all the transform/business logic on one (or at least fewer) schema(s). This is important, especially when on-boarding new developers. Also, permissions are often provided on schema level. You often want to give some sort of end-user access to the dimensional objects, but not to raw/stage data. Depending on your ETL load and data, schemas might also be something that can be used to determine what objects can be loaded in parallell to reduce overall load times.